# Workato - Hash containing an array when sent in a multipart form request is considered as a file

Tags: multipartform-data, workato

I am trying to send an array as value for a hash key in a POST multipart request.

```
input = {"attribute"=> ["Countries:India", "Category:Can"]}
post("url")
.request_format_multipart_form.payload(input)
```

This works when using Ruby's HTTP and also POSTMAN. I can also see the differences between how Postman and Workato handles the form data.

**Postman:**

```
----------------------------428750340837882951989223
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attribute"
Category:Test
----------------------------428750340837882951989223
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attribute"
Countries:India
----------------------------428750340837882951989223--
```

**Workato:**

```
------RubyFormBoundaryhokO7A27Xb6cdSEz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attribute"; filename="attribute"
Content-Type: Category:Can

Countries:India
------RubyFormBoundaryhokO7A27Xb6cdSEz--
```

Why does Workato consider an array as a file? or am I wrong with the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the request type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and encode the input parameters as form data in the body (Using `encode_www_form`).

```
input = {"attribute"=> ["Countries:India", "Category:Can"]}
input = input.encode_www_form
post("url",input)
.request_format_www_form_urlencoded
```